# Select multiple rows from database (same field, multiple conditions)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the below dataset, how would I select rows that meet both of these conditions

`field` = 'Are they covered at the moment' AND `value` = TRUE

`field` = 'Where does the client operate from' AND `value` = Home

If both conditions don't match then no records are to be returned

This isn't limited to just two conditions, there could be 1 condition or 5 for example that need to be met (based on the query being passed in)

| name | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Are they covered at the moment | TRUE |
| A | Where does the client operate from | Home |
| A | Additional information | x |
| B | Are they covered at the moment | TRUE |
| B | Where does the client operate from | Work |
| B | Additional information | x |

**Expected Output #1**

Based on the below conditions

`field` = 'Are they covered at the moment' AND `value` = TRUE

`field` = 'Where does the client operate from' AND `value` = Home

Would be:

| name | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Are they covered at the moment | TRUE |
| A | Where does the client operate from | Home |
| A | Additional information | x |

**Expected Output #2**

Based on the below conditions

`field` = 'Additional information' AND `value` = x

Would be:

| name | field | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Are they covered at the moment | TRUE |
| A | Where does the client operate from | Home |
| A | Additional information | x |
| B | Are they covered at the moment | TRUE |
| B | Where does the client operate from | Work |
| B | Additional information | x |

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the expected output

Comment: Please add the desired result (based on your sample).  It seems that you need either `EXISTS` or *conditional aggregation*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `group by` and `having` clauses to get names that satisfy both conditions :

```
select name
from mytable
group by name
having count(case when field = 'Are they covered at the moment' AND value = 'TRUE' then 1 end) >= 1
       and count(case when field = 'Where does the client operate from' AND value = 'Home' then 1 end) >= 1;
```

Then join this dataset with the table to get the expected output :

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select name
  from mytable
  group by name
  having count(case when field = 'Are they covered at the moment' AND value = 'TRUE' then 1 end) >= 1
       and count(case when field = 'Where does the client operate from' AND value = 'Home' then 1 end) >= 1
) as s on s.name = t.name;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7OaprT1r)

Comment: That's clever, thank you!